# Upload data up to blank row/Dynamic Last row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
bulk insert TABLEFORTEST
from 'E:\Test.txt'
with (firstrow = 9,fieldterminator = '|',rowterminator = '\n')
go
```

But I want to upload data up to Blank Row found in file.

How can I, Kindly suggest query.

Is it possible to do using Dynamic Last row?

How to find Number of rows in TXT file?

Comment: [There](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) is no `LAST_ROW` parameter to `BULK_INSERT`. You'll have to pre-process the data yourself.

Comment: Find the byte offset of two \n in succession and truncate the file to that length